# DateDiff of dates in the same column from same group SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, datediff

I need to get the differences in days between an order and the previous from same user

ORDERS TABLE:

```
customer_id    id       Activation_time
-----------------------------------------------------
1               1       2016-02-10 13:41:50.000
1               2       2018-03-10 18:42:45.000
1.              3       2019-05-18 15:55:04.000
.
.
.
```

I have no idea so any help will be really appreciate !!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: How is the `2` in the first row calculated?

Comment: My bad, sorry. Already fixed it

Answer (score 2):

You can use window functions.  It looks like this:

```
select o.*,
       datediff(activation_time, lag(activation_time) over (partition by  customer_id order by activation_time) as Days_since_last_order
from orders o;
```

Note this will return `NULL` for the earliest activation.  I'm not sure why your data has "2".

I prefer `NULL` for the earliest date, but if you want `0`, you can use:

```
select o.*,
       datediff(activation_time,
                lag(activation_time, 1, activation_time) over (partition by  customer_id order by activation_time
               ) as Days_since_last_order
from orders o;
```

That is, add a default argument to `LAG()`.